# Webpack + babel not working with IE 11, but babel alone works

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have a `index.js` which uses ES9 (es2018 syntax):

```
// from wikipedia
let object = {a: 1, b: 2}
let objectClone = {...object} // ES9 syntax
let otherObject = {c: 3, ...object}
console.log(otherObject) // -> {c: 3, a: 1, b: 2}
```

I want to run this code in Internet Explorer 11 (not edge). It already works fine in Chrome, but not in IE. Babel can convert to vanilla js, which can run in IE.

---

**Babel Setup:**

`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

`.babelrc`

```
{ "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"] }
```

I run the babel command, and point an `index.html` to the `dist/bundle.js` location. It works fine:

```
npx babel .\index.js --out-file dist/bundle.js
```

[image]

---

**Webpack Setup:**

`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        options: { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"] }
      } 
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js']
  }
};
```

I run `npx webpack`, it executes without error, but IE does not output anything. I think the reason is because the `dist/bundle.js` has an arrow function when it gets minified, which IE cannot understand.

In summary, this works with babel, but not webpack. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputenvironment might be what you are looking for. You probably want to set all of those options to `false`.

Comment: If your project does not have the `.browserslistrc` file then create one and add `ie <= 11` in it. Further, try to add necessary polyfills and you can refer to this helpful [article](https://www.thebasement.be/working-with-babel-7-and-webpack/) may give you some hint to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Babel would only compile the code you write, and that arrow seems to be webpack generated runtime code, hence not compiled by babel.

Since you're using webpack 5, try to set [`target`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/target/#string-1) to `['web', 'es5']` if you're not using `browserslistrc`.